# Adding fields to a hash

Tags: ruby

I am getting the following error for the code below

```
undefined method `push=' for {"organisation_id"=>1}:Hash
```

If the param for role is passed in the URL I want to add that on as a query parameter. I am coming from a PHP dev background so I'm finding it difficult managing Rails Objects/Arrays.

```
def index
    case @the_current_user.role
      when 'admin'
        query_params = {"organisation_id"=> @the_current_user.organisation_id}
      else
        query_params = {"organisation_id" => @the_current_user.organisation_id, "team_id" => @the_current_user.team_id}
    end

    if params[:role]
      query_params.push = {"role" => params[:role]}
    end

    @users = User.all(query_params).offset(@offset.to_i).limit(@limit.to_i)
    render json: @users
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby if you want to merge two hash then use the `Hash#merge` method. Try this:

```
query_params.merge!({"role" => params[:role]})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing that query_params is a Hash and not an Array. You can't push values to hash. You can set the value of a key in a hash.
So you can do it like this

```
query_params["role"] = params[:role]
```